# Weird behavior of smart card reader

Tags: nfc, smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I have a [CRT-603-CZ1](http://www.hitools-access.com/upload/CRT-603-CZ1%20Contactless%20Card%20Reader%20Module%20User%20Manual%20DOC.pdf) smart card reader and I want to read 16 bytes of block 4 of a classic 1k Mifare contactless card. The authentication keys are the defualt values (i.e `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF`). So I must send 3 commands to the reader as below :

1. Load Key APDU command
2. Authenticate APDU command
3. Read Block Data

(*The corresponding APDU commands are mentioned in the above manual.*)

In order to send above APDU commands, I used [OpenSCTool](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/QuickStart) and you can see the result in the following:

```java
OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF -s FF860000050100046000 -s FFB000
0410
Using reader with a card: CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0
Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF -s FF860000050100046000 -s FFB000
0410
Using reader with a card: CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0
Sending: FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: FF B0 00 04 10
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF -s FF860000050100046000 -s FFB000
0410
Using reader with a card: CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0
Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF -s FF860000050100046000 -s FFB000
0410
Using reader with a card: CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0
Sending: FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: FF B0 00 04 10
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF -s FF860000050100046000 -s FFB000
0410
Using reader with a card: CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0
Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled

OpenSCTool:> OSC.exe -s FF82000006FFFFFFFFFFFF -s FF860000050100046000 -s FFB000
0410
Using reader with a card: CREATOR CRT-603 (CZ1) CCR RF 0
Sending: FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00
Received (SW1=0x69, SW2=0x83)
Sending: FF B0 00 04 10
Received (SW1=0x69, SW2=0x82)

OpenSCTool:>
```

As you see above, I tried these there commands more than one time. but I didn't receive the same response.

- Sometimes I receive an error "*Failed to connect to card: Card is invalid or cannot be handled*"
- Sometimes all three command return `0x9000`,`0x9000` and `0x9000` as the status words.
- And sometimes I receive `0x9000`, `0x6983` and `0x6982` as the APDU response status words.

*Note that I don't change anything about the reader or card during repeating above command. Everything is fixed.*

What's wrong?

**Update:**

Note that this reader has a tool that it works fine for the same APDU commands. Look:

[image]

These are contents of log section:

```java
SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF   Receive Buffer : 90 00 

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00     Receive Buffer : 90 00

SCardTransmit...OK    Send Buffer : FF B0 00 04 10     Receive Buffer : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00
```

As you see, all the response for different tries are equal.

So

1. can I conclude "There is no problem with the reader, and there is a problem with the OpenSCTool"?
2. How can I solve this issue?

**Update 2:**

I wrote a Python program using PySCard library to send above three commands in a row for 5 times. And all the five series have successful equal result (i.e `0x9000` for all 5*3 =15 commands). So it seems that there is problem with OpenSCTool.but I don't know what is the problem and why it respond like this.